# How to manage parallel, dependent inheritance in C++?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I'm trying to solve a problem involving parallel inheritance in C++. The nearest question I've found for this is [Parallel inheritance trees, where classes from one tree have containers of classes from another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779489/parallel-inheritance-trees-where-classes-from-one-tree-have-containers-of-class), but it doesn't quite answer my problem.

I have a model consisting of three classes: Model, Trainer, InstanceProcessor (IP), which contain the model data, training functions and model processing code, respectively. Now I have about 10 different versions of this model, with a lot of code overlapping but some differences, creating some form of parallel inheritance:

```
Model - ModelA, ModelB, ModelC, ...
Trainer - TrainerA, TrainerB, TrainerC
IP - IPA, IPB, IPC
```

In the main body of code I use a Model* pointer to access a particular model depending on arguments parsed.

Both Model and Trainer require multiple, short-lived instances of IP, Model further requires a permanent instance of Trainer.

My current implementation uses three base classes with some virtual functions and then model specific classes inheriting from these base classes. This requires me to use a lot of casting (eg. from the Trainer* trainer in model.h to TrainerA for a specific need).

I suspect there is a more elegant way of implementing this (using templates/interfaces?), and was wondering if anyone could point me into the right direction? Thanks!

---

Edit: To clarify a point from the answers below, one of the complexities lies in the fact that I want eg. the Trainer classes to have a function basic_train():

```
Trainer::basicTraining() {
    ...
    IP* ip = new IP(some args);
    ip->doStuff();
    ...
}
```

where now the appropriate IP is created, depending on the type of trainer used. The rest of that function does not change from TrainerA to TrainerB instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When members of two separate hierarchies are tightly coupled, inheritance does not buy you much. Inheritance [promises](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) that mix-and-match strategies should be possible (i.e. using `ModelA` with `TrainerB` and an `IPC`) when in fact this is not going to work.

One very important thing to realize, however, is that the interface the the model, trainer, and IP present to each other may be different from the interface that they collectively present to your main application: the main application sees them as groups of uniform objects, while each subgroup of model/trainer/IP (i.e. `A`, `B`, `C` groups) treat members of the same group as highly specialized. Therefore, although the inheritance may be bad for the individual parts of your inheritance hierarchy, it may be good for your main program.

This leads you to a viable solution of using an [*abstract factory*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) pattern. The main application gets a "factory of factories" that can give it a `FactoryA`, `FactoryB`, or `FactoryC` based on whatever it passes in. Each `FactoryX` produces `ModelX`, `TrainerX`, and `IPX` objects, presenting them to your main program as their common superclasses (i.e. `Model`, `Trainer`, and `IP`).

In the guts of the factory, however, the implementing objects are created with the knowledge of their "counterpart"'s exact type. For example, when `ModelA` is configured with a `Trainer`, it does not take an object of type `Trainer` - it gets `TrainerA`. Since `FactoryA` knows the dependencies between the objects that it creates, it has no problem supplying objects of the right type. At the same time, the main program has no idea of this specialization, and the parts (`ModelA`, `TrainerA`, and `IPA`) have little idea of the generalization.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, this seems like the most suitable pattern from the ones suggested so far. I've updated my question to clarify the need for inheritance among my three classes, but I guess this is a separate issue on top of the first one solved with the abstract factory.

Comment: @Martin The way I see it, the biggest dilemma here is that your main program wants inheritance, but your implementations hate it (hence going for type casting a lot). As far as your edit goes, you can abstract out the process of creating objects (i.e. things like `IP* ip = new IP(some args);` in the trainer) by making a pure virtual function `IP *createIp(some args)`, and implementing it in each trainer to return `new IPA(args)`, `new IPB(args)`, etc.

Comment: @daslinkenlight - that makes sense. Would I stick those virtual functions into the AbstractFactory or into the AbstractIP class in that case? It would work in either place, but I guess the AbstractFactory would be the appropriate place? And related to that, is it standard that the specific classes (ModelA, TrainerA, IPA) are passed a pointer to their factory for creating instances of each other?

Comment: @Martin You can certainly deal with all creation issues through the same AbstractFactory, giving a reference to it to all related "interested parties". However, since the AbstractFactory is there to hide the details from the main program, one concern is that it would hide too much from the participants. You can start by giving the same factory to all participants, but if its abstract nature starts becoming an issue, you could always move the code back to the individual classes (i.e. put `TrainerB` in charge of creating `new IPB()` for the `Trainer`'s base class).

Answer (score 1):

Basically casting is bad, because it's brittle (you'll forget to update the code when you are supposed to). Rather, you should harness polymorphism. I think you might want to have a look at the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern), which would perhaps match your initial idea of using interfaces.

Comment: Personally I really like using templates and "compile-time duck typing" in C++, but (given the relatively low amount of information about your specific situation) I think they might not be exactly what you need here.

Comment: Thanks, I've just read up on the visitor pattern. That could work for aspects of my problem. Out of curiosity, how would a solution for this look like with templates? I have a vague understanding of templates, but am not quite sure how I could use them in this setting (editing problem now to make it a bit clearer).

Comment: Based on your updated question, it's getting harder and harder to see how templates could help you. They are a really great tool, but not necessarily for this problem.

Comment: They might be helpful in a situation where you have a function train(Trainer& trainer), and you need to be able to pass TrainerA and TrainerB, which however are not connected via inheritance, but do have some method that has identical name and takes same arguments. Then, inside train() you could just calls trainer.foo(5), which would work even though TrainerA and TrainerB have no connection (other than the similar-looking method, hence the term 'duck typing').

Answer (score 0):

To put it in more abstract terms: You have a set of classes which are already fixed with respect to inheritance and you want to make each of them behave differently depending on the use case.

In situations like this most of the time **dependency injection** or a **policy** helps: you can do this for every method-call or you can decide it when an object is created.

In the first case you pass in - as an argument - something (see below) that changes the method's behavior.

In the second case you pass that argument to the constructor and the object has to store that 'something'.

The 'something' could be as simple as a fixed set of values (eg enum) or be a callback/functor/lambda or an object. Choose whatever is comfortable, the point is that it can change the behavior of the objects even if they are all of the same class.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I think my problem is a bit more complicated than that. The behaviour and structure of the models varies significantly based on their type, so pushing all of that logic into a single class would make things overly complex - unless I'm misunderstanding your suggested solution.

Comment: Avoiding that is exactly what dependency injection is good at: For example assume you have a Player-class that should have different behaviors (but cannot get them through inheritance because that was set in stone); having different behaviors is possible by injecting an onAction-callback to the player. If the Player has to respond to an action it can call that callback and let the callback decide what to do.